# `Missing header/body separator` in wordpress `wp_remote_get` call

Tags: php, wordpress, macos

In my local development machine i see following error

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
    (
        [http_request_failed] => Array
            (
                [0] => Missing header/body separator
            )

    )

[error_data] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

This is simple get request with

```
wp_remote_get( 'https://www.google.com/' );
```

But when i request the same using command line i get the HTML response

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

I am use macOS Mojave 10.14.5 with PHP 7.2.18

Comment: Curl php extension is enabled on your dev machine?

Comment: yes, version 7.65.0 while i check phpinfo

Comment: Other urls fetch without troubles?

Comment: Have you tried this with a URL from a different domain than google.com? Google probably has a lot of measures in place trying to detect “bots”, so maybe the response you are getting is a different one than you expected, and perhaps different from what you get with the plain cURL request as well.

Comment: i have tried with other url as well. same result

Comment: Are you sure that curl extension is enabled? Php might be compiled with curl, but this is does not mean that extension is enabled. Please attach your `phpinfo` output.